# XCode4.6 on iOS7 - select row on UITableView and present PopoverController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uipopovercontroller

I have a `UITableView` in which onSelect each row I will present a `UIPopoverController` that looks like the one below.

[image: ideal scenario screenshot]

This all works very well on an iOS 6 device. However, I get a strange problem when the code gets deployed onto an iOS 7 device. Note that I am building this project on XCode 5 with the XCode 4.6 SDK. When and only when I select the **4th** row, the alignment of the `PopoverController` goes haywire. The below is a screenshot of the misaligned `PopoverController`.

[image: haywire scenario screenshot]

What could be possibly wrong? The below is my code for the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` :

```
    // get location of cell being pressed.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // 600 and 10 represent the location in which the cell arrow pops
    CGRect rect=CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x+300, cell.frame.origin.y+100, 50, 30);

    // show popover for EditQueue
    EditQueueViewController *editQueueViewController = [[EditQueueViewController alloc] init];
    editQueueViewController.queueToEdit = thisQueue;
    editQueuePopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:editQueueViewController];
    editQueuePopover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(423, 280);
    [self.editQueuePopover presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft | UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been to there during my summer job, so maybe you need to switch back to Xcode 4.6 (as in, real Xcode 4.6, not just the SDK, it runs on Mavericks).

Alternatively, you can do a little OS check and load different UI for iOS 6 and 7 (and embrace new iOS 7 look and feel there)

Comment: great thanks for the reply. But I cant submit apps with Xcode 4.6 can I? Actually, I am not even sure if Apple will accept apps built with the SDK4.6 anyway. :(

Comment: @user1258600 You can. (There are even apps from old Xcode 3.x)